# Validate hotel room availability

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say 'A' and 'B' are two kinds of rooms. The hotel has 10 'A' rooms and 5 'B' rooms. When the user books one 'A' room, 'A' should be 9 and 'B' still as 5 in the availability check.

How do I this?
This should be done using JavaScript in HTML.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please add what you have already worked on. also see the http://stackoverflow.com/faq about what kind of questions you should ask here

Comment: This question needs punctuation, rewriting, and example of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you haven't even tried anything so far and have no ideas around how to possibly implement this - which suggests that you have little knowledge around how to tackle problems with a software-program-based solution. I would suggest that you read up on the fundamentals of problem solving and modelling real-world scenarios using software/programs. I would also suggest Douglas Crockford's lectures and writings on JavaScript as an excellent resource.

There are an infinite number of ways you could address this problem. Is this data to be stored in a database? Or is it just purely a "theoretical" exercise in JS. You *could* do it like this...

```
function hotel(){
    var a_rooms = 10; 
    var b_rooms = 5;

    return {
        total_rooms : 
            function() { 
                return a_rooms + b_rooms;
            } ,
        book_a : 
            function(){ 
                if (a_rooms > 0) { 
                    a_rooms--;
                    return "A room booked (" + a_rooms + ") left";
                } else {
                    return "no A rooms left";
                }
            } ,
        book_b :
            function(){ 
                if (b_rooms > 0) { 
                    b_rooms--;
                    return "A room booked (" + b_rooms + ") left";
                } else {
                    return "no B rooms left";
                }
            }
    };
};
```

As in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uXCXE/3/)